# 100% resizable divs floating left inside container div

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Is it possible to have a container div with X child divs, each one 100% resizable in the browser? I know it can be done with a single background, but not with a row of divs...
This is what I intend to do (slideshow that slides left/right):

[image]

The HTML:

```html
<div id="slideshowContent">
  <div id="slideshowImage_01" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
  <div id="slideshowImage_02" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
  <div id="slideshowImage_03" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
  <div id="slideshowImage_04" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
</div> <!-- End of id="slideshowContent" -->
```

... and the CSS:

```css
#slideshowContainer {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 11520px; height: 1080px;
  position: relative;
}

.slideshowImage {
  width: 1920px; height: 1080px;
  float: left;
}
```

Thanx.

Pedro

**EDIT 1: I forgot to mention that each individual div contains an image.**

**EDIT 2: Added my own updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t2xjH/).**

Comment: +1 for your image. anyway is this helpful? http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example/

Comment: Have you tried something like using % ?

Comment: Yes, but it's not that simple...

Comment: @Pedro it is, actually. I'm creating a fiddle right now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's fully working version: http://jsfiddle.net/y9zcf/7/

The centering is done using CSS, the javascript is just to run the slideshow.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshowWrapper">
    <div id="slideshowContent">
        <div id="slideshowImage_01" class="slideshowImage_container active"></div>
        <div id="slideshowImage_02" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
        <div id="slideshowImage_03" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
        <div id="slideshowImage_04" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#slideshowWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#slideshowContent {
    width: 400%; // 100% * number of slides
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#slideshowContent .slideshowImage_container {
    width: 25%; // 100% / number of slides
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function slide() {
    var container = $('#slideshowContent'),
        nextDiv = container.find('.active').next('div'),
        slides = container.find('div'),
        next = nextDiv.length ? nextDiv : slides.first();

    slides.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
    $('#slideshowContent').animate({
        'left': '-' + next.index() * next.width() + 'px'
    }, 2000, function () {
        $(this).css({
            'left': '-' + next.index() * 100 + '%'
        });
    });

}

setInterval(function () {
    slide();
}, 5000);
```

This is 100% resizable and `#slideshowWrapper` can be set to any width/height and the divs inside will work fine. Setting the CSS to a percent value **after** animating means that the divs are still resizable after the transition.

Comment: Thanx for the Fiddle. I think that any images inside the divs are not not resizing - [Your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eEgnQ/).

Comment: @Pedro - I've just updated you fiddle to make it work - http://jsfiddle.net/eEgnQ/1/ - if you're just making an image slideshow then I'd recommend taking a look at: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: @Pedro - Here's a quick `backstretch` plugin example: http://jsfiddle.net/y9zcf/10/

Comment: `width: 400%; // 100% * number of slides` makes it very static and not dynamic

Comment: @Si8 - this could be defined dynamically using js via inline styles. The answer's CSS is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of is using javascript

**CSS**

```
#SlideShow {
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshowContent {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 11520px; 
  height: 1080px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}

.slideshowImage_container img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.slideWidth = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    window.onresize = funciton() {
        var window.slideWidth = jQUery("#SlideShow").width();
        jQuery("#slideshowContent slideshowImage_container").css("width",window.slideWidth+"px");
        jQuery("#slideshowContent").css("left","0px"); //or adjust the left to the current slide show image since they are now different lengths and the slideshow will be off.
    }
    window.resize();
});
```

And setup your slide techniques to use window.slideWidth as the sliding amount
And just slide `#slideshowContent` left or right.

**HTML**

```
<div id="SlideShow">
  <div id="slideshowContent">
    <div id="slideshowImage_01" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
    <div id="slideshowImage_02" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
    <div id="slideshowImage_03" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
    <div id="slideshowImage_04" class="slideshowImage_container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have defined the width you would like to use so I suggest using a max-width along with a 100% width to see if that fixes your problem.

```
#slideshowContainer {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1520px; 
  position: relative;
}

.slideshowImage {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px; 
  float: left;
}
```

If you leave out height it should calculate it automatically.  If you do not feel comfortable leaving out the height you could set the height like you would the width...

```
height: auto;
max-height: 1080px;
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an horizontal CSS base without positionning nor floating would interest you.

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#slideshowWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;
}
#slideshowWrapper:hover {

}
#slideshowContent {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-indent:0;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.slideshowImage_container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
    text-indent:normal;
    text-align:center;
}
#slideshowImage_01 {
    background-color: #A0D0A8;
}
#slideshowImage_02 {
    background-color: #009FE3;
}
#slideshowImage_03 {
    background-color: #FCC99A;
}
#slideshowImage_04 {
    background-color: #D8B0CB;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/PfbnW/1/

With CSS animation as extra :
(just for the show, js 's more solid )
not so flexible, it needs to be set every time you add or remove a container.

```
#slideshowWrapper {
    animation: slidemeAnyDir 30s infinite;
    animation-play-state:running;
}
#slideshowWrapper:hover {
    animation-play-state:paused;
}

@keyframes slidemeAnyDir {
      0%, 15%, 100%      {text-indent:0;}
    17%, 32%,  84%, 98%  {text-indent:-100%;}
    34%, 49%,  68%, 82%  {text-indent:-200%;}
    51%, 66%%            {text-indent:-300%;}
}
```

Why text-indent ?
because it can react perfectly to direction in wich the document shows on screen.
It will slides sides that direction is set on parent or by default.

Comment: This is great except the `400%` is a static width, so what happens if the content is updated by someone else? Now there is 5 DIVs but only has 400% width :/

Comment: @Si8 Then leave a comment in html/css to tell and explain how to update CSS in front HTML updates. IF you do not want to bother with this, then use javascript to set on the fly  those values, this is a typical js job. Besides that randomn number of DIV is not in the question

Comment: Definitely I agree with you and the question wasn't asking for dynamic # for the divs.